# How to run this script in mac terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

Im trying to run the following script in terminal:

```
python write_tfrecords
--dataset_dir /Users/shwaitkumar/Desktop/NLP/Text Detection/Synthetic Train Set - Detection & Recognition
--save_dir /Users/shwaitkumar/Desktop/NLP/Text Detection/untitled folder
```

but I'm not able to run it. If i run it one by one, it gives me error in line 1 that path is not defined and if i try to paste it all and run i get another error, bash : -- command not found.
how do i run this script in terminal? I even created a conda environment to run this but still same error.

Comment: Is your python file just "write_tfrecords" not "write_tfrecords.py"? Also these are three lines, make three lines in a single line, then it should be fine.

Comment: Yes it worked but it gives me error unrecognised arguments

Comment: can you post you code, what library are you using to parse args arg_parse or click (https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)

Comment: I'm just using this script to create tfrecords but my database is different. Here's the link for script : (https://github.com/MaybeShewill-CV/CRNN_Tensorflow/blob/master/tools/write_tfrecords.py)

Comment: There are spaces in ur folder name, I think thats causing the problem, enclosed folder paths in quotes "/Users/shwaitkumar/Desktop/NLP/Text Detection/Synthetic Train Set - Detection & Recognition"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be three issues with how you are executing:

1. write_tfrecords should be "write_tfrecords.py"
2. Three lines should be combined into one single line
3. Arg values (folder name) have spaces in it, they should be enclosed in quotes.

   python write_tfrecords.py --dataset_dir "/Users/shwaitkumar/Desktop/NLP/Text Detection/Synthetic Train Set - Detection & Recognition" --save_dir "/Users/shwaitkumar/Desktop/NLP/Text Detection/untitled folder"